# thread.join() problem in java

Tags: java, multithreading

**My Code**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Thread1");
            }
        });
        thread1.join();
        thread1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Sometimes "Thread1" gets printed even before all the numbers get printed. Any reason for that? Shouldn't Thread1 should wait until main thread gets completed?

Comment: Aravind, what do you expect to happen? numbers 1st, then "Thread1"? If so start the thread AFTER printing and wait (join()) AFTER start()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    thread1.join();
    thread1.start()
```

make it

```
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join();
```

It will start a thread from main thread by `thread1.start()` and main thread will continue to execute at the very next line it will see  `thread1.join();` which will pause main thread's execution until thread1 finishes. so your work will get done

Answer (score 1):

By calling `Thread.join()` The current thread waits for the thread you are calling `join()`.

In you case you are waiting for `thread1` to complete before it even started.

If you want `thread1` to wait for the numbers to complete printing, you can use a `CountDownLatch` [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
public class Main {
    public static final CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    startSignal.await();
                    System.out.println("Thread1");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
        });
        thread1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        startSignal.countDown();
        thread1.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: why use a latch? just start the thread after the numbers, it's way more natural.

Comment: @bestsss I am assuming the OP is doing other things in `thread1`, otherwise this wouldn't be a question.

Comment: I Guess thread1.join() is not necessary.... But this is a new method to make threads wait(As far as i know ;))

Comment: I just dont know, the only clue available is *Shouldn't Thread1 should wait until main thread gets completed?*, which seems like a start-up initialization stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that you should call `thread1.start()` before `thread1.join()` you actually don't know when the thread will be executed. It can happen while printing your `i`, it could happen before or it could happen after. Depends on the thread scheduling mechanism of your OS. Your correct code should look like this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Thread1");
        }
    });
    // start the thread
    thread1.start();
    // print the numbers... meanwhile your thread *could* get executed
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    // wait for thread1 to finish
    thread1.join();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we should make sure the system has started the thread in accordance with our ".start()" request (which doesn't necessarily happen before start() returns), before invoking join(), as join() does not really wait until a thread dies, rather, it simply returns as soon as a thread isn't running. This can happen before the thread starts, or after it finishes. See "Taming Java Threads" by Allen Holub, page 87. Here is what I feel is the correct way to write this code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
```

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    final Semaphore waitForThreadToStart = new Semaphore (0);

    Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            waitForThreadToStart.release();
            System.out.println("Thread1");
        }
    });

    thread1.start();
    waitForThreadToStart.acquire();  // Wait for thread to start

    thread1.join(); // Now do the join.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

}